# Navigation- & Toolbar not hidden when UIScrollView scrolls

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, contentoffset

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffset.y) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The UIScrollViewDelegate is already set in my header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move

```
lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
```

to the end of the method, otherwise

```
scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffset.y
```

will never be true.

Comment: why is the second line in your answer wrong? do you know where the error is?

Comment: If you set `lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset` then `scrollView.contentOffset.y` is equal to `lastOffset.y`.

Comment: the bars should hide when the user scrolls down. how do I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Move the statement `lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset` to the end of the method?

Comment: yes, it's at the end now. But as you already said: `scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffset.y` is invalid. how can I fix that? this is my problem :)

Comment: Where is `lastOffset` declared?

Comment: it's just alloc'd in my header file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15984/discussion-between-martin-r-and-sascha-wieland)

Answer (score 1):

It's not hidden because every time code in *else* part is invoked.
Suppose contentOffset = (100, 100)
then you set last offset to equal contentOffset so `if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffset.y)` it will never be true. Put `lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;` on the end of scrollViewDidScroll method.